# Refresh one layer style

Tags: pyqgis

I have a layer with a style that I save

[image]

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.saveNamedStyle('F:/test.qml')
```

I modify the style of the layer

[image]

I want to run a script to apply a qml style to a layer.

```
layer.loadNamedStyle('F:/test.qml')
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

my line of code works *if I modify the zoom level with the mouse wheel*.

**Why isn't refreshing done alone?**

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the call you are missing is `layer.triggerRepaint()`

Try:

```py
style_path = r'Path\to\style_file.qml'

lyr = iface.activeLayer()

lyr.loadNamedStyle(style_path)

lyr.triggerRepaint()

# update legend symbology (shouldn't be needed)
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(lyr.id())
```